# Open Layer-> Simple Program Of Tile.Image not working

Tags: openlayers

I am using ***“Open Layer”*** for developing a map.

Below is my program but it's giving me error : "***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method

'containsLonLat' of null***"

```
<script src="/OpenLayers-2.11/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

//map created
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

//Vector layer created
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay",{isBaseLayer:false});

var size=OpenLayers.Size(500,500);

bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(4,5));
bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(5,6));

imageTile=OpenLayers.Tile.Image(vectorLayer,new OpenLayers.Pixel(12,35),bounds,'http://www.bigfoto.com/themes/nature/landscapes/kosamui-thailand_small.JPG',size);

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71, 42);
point.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject());

map.setCenter(point,3);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();

</script>
```

Please correct me what's wrong in this program I shall be thankful to all of you.

Gajendra

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I had to specify my base layer ;

```
...
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
map.setBaseLayer(vectorLayer);
...
```